# Input regarding this PHP script to query a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was using this script and everything was great except for the fact that when the actual search was executed and "No Results" was the answer, I wanted the script to display such.

When doing research to see where the FAIL was I discovered that I should be using MySQLi. I have been at this script for 2 days and I seem to be getting further instead of closer. A little help here fellas?

What I am using:

```
    if(empty($_GET['query'])){
header ("Location: /same_page");
}
else{
//connect
include 'connection_script.php';

//Get the "Term" from the search box
$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$page_str = "SELECT * FROM $tblname WHERE name like '%$query%' or clan like '%$query%'";

$page_query = mysqli_query($con,$page_str)or die(mysql_error($con));

while($page_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_query)){$datarow .= " <ul>
<li>Banned player : <a target='_blank' href=\"http://path/tosomething/here=" . $page_result[name] . " \">" . $page_result[name] . "</a></li>
<li>Clan Name : " . $page_result[clan] . "</li> 
<li>Reason : " . $page_result[reason] . "</li>
<li>Posted By : " . $page_result[moderator] . "</li>
<li>Date & Time : " . $page_result[dateandtime] . "</li>
<li>Evidence : <a target='_blank' href=\"$page_result[evidence]\">Here</a></li>
</ul><br />";
}

echo $datarow;
echo "<br />";

include 'dbclose.php';
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: You should not be mixing mysql_ and msqli_ functions in the same script. Stick with one, or better yet migrate to PDO

Comment: Isn't the right way to get value of an array by key is $page_result['name']?

Comment: I am learning quicky that what you are saying is true about the mixing. It was not my intention to try and mix the two. I have just simply found out that I should no longer be using mysql_*. This is me in the process of converting.

Comment: I guess I am going to have to write this entire script over again? I can't seem to find any examples from anywhere let alone anyone to even AGREE on whether is should be OO or procedural.

Comment: yeh, surround your column names in '' - EG $page_result['moderator']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition to display something if your query returns 0

```
      if(empty($_GET['query'])){
header ("Location: /same_page");
}
else{
//connect
include 'connection_script.php';

//Get the "Term" from the search box
$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$page_str = "SELECT * FROM $tblname WHERE name like '%$query%' or clan like '%$query%'";

$page_query = mysqli_query($con,$page_str)or die(mysql_error($con));

if (mysqli_num_rows($page_query) > 0){

while($page_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_query)){$datarow .= " <ul>
<li>Banned player : <a target='_blank' href=\"http://path/tosomething/here=" . $page_result[name] . " \">" . $page_result[name] . "</a></li>
<li>Clan Name : " . $page_result[clan] . "</li> 
<li>Reason : " . $page_result[reason] . "</li>
<li>Posted By : " . $page_result[moderator] . "</li>
<li>Date & Time : " . $page_result[dateandtime] . "</li>
<li>Evidence : <a target='_blank' href=\"$page_result[evidence]\">Here</a></li>
</ul><br />";
}

echo $datarow;
echo "<br />";
} else {
echo 'Your search returned 0 results';
}

include 'dbclose.php';
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Thank you for you response, Dave. When I inserted your added conditional the script would no longer search. So that must not be the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Returning to mark this as [resolved]. I would like to add that all answers are actually correct. My problem remained due to my lack of knowledge with the new format of MySQLi_. I would also like to share that I found an example to use [here](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2012/02/php-ajax-pagination-mysqli-version.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the count of the rows with:

```
mysqli_num_rows($page_query);
```

Simply verify that it is `>0` to chose what to display, the error message or the results